# Вывод значения переменной в ответ на команду /random

Tags: python, telebot

Хочу реализовать вывод значения переменной `a`. Мой код вроде бы выполняется,но при вызове команды `/random` он не выводит пользователю значение переменной.

```
import telebot
import random

list1=["Да", "Нет", "Скорее да чем нет", "Скорее нет чем да", "Спроси еще раз"]
a=(random.choice(list1))
print(a)

    


bot = telebot.TeleBot("")#ваш токен


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "❗️Бот запущен❗️")
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgIAAxkBAAECIm1gZi2ltgsW2ZyoCaLrJPufJilQiwACKgMAAs-71A4f8rUYf2WfMB4E")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "здравствуйте":
        bot.reply_to(message, "Приветствую вас,сударь!" )
    if message.text.lower() =="привет":
        bot.reply_to(message, "Привет,друг!")
    if message.text.lower() =="здарова":
        bot.reply_to(message, "Ну здравствуй,отец.")
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, "CAACAgIAAxkBAAECJSxgaikPv6KdgYrq_htRZfBTvzYQ1QACIQADdJypFv67iftKv6O5HgQ")
    if message.text.lower() =="пока":
        bot.reply_to(message, "Бувай, хлопец")
    if message.text.lower() == "как дела?":
        bot.reply_to(message, "Заработался уже")
    elif message.text.lower() == "как дела":
        bot.reply_to(message, "У меня прекрасно.Как ты?")
        
        
        
@bot.message_handler(commands=['random'])
def start_message(message):
    list1=["Да", "Нет", "Скорее да чем нет", "Скорее нет чем да", "Спроси еще раз"]
    a=(random.choice(list1))
    bot.send_message(message, f'Думаю ответ: {a}')

    

bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно вместо message написать message.chat.id

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Думаю ответ: {a}')
# Или
bot.reply_to(message, f'Думаю ответ: {a}')
```

Подробнее про [Телебот апи](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) и [Телеграм бот апи](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

P.S У вас одинаковые названия 1 и 3 функции, это может привести к конфликту в дальнейшем.

Comment: Большое спасибо!Работает!И спасибо за то что нашли мою ошибку про названия функций)